# Any hope for these pepper seedlings?

Tags: seedlings, peppers, stress

I don’t know what happened, but these two pepper seedlings have gone completely limp. They’ve been in this state for a few days and still seem to be clinging to life. There is no sign of insects or fungus and the roots seem ok. Is there any chance they’ll recover?[image]

update: I’m now thinking this could be salt injury. I heard that epsom salt is good for peppers and I gave these two some. Maybe I overdid it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your seedlings look to be suffering from "damping off" — a fungal disease that is generally due to overwatering when seedlings are young. Indeed, your media looks very wet. Seedlings of this size do not need a lot of water, just enough to keep the media damp. In my opinion, these guys are toast. You'll be better off discarding these seedlings and starting over.